# Access Azure API in Python

Tags: python, azure, api, http, get

My boss sent me an url which has the following format:

https://{appname}.azurewebsites.net/api/Authentication/Token?username=XXXX&password=YYYY

I would like to access the api and fetch the data from a python script. 
I did the following in script :

```
import requests

response= requests.get("https://{appname}.azurewebsites.net/", 
                       auth=('XXXX', 'YYYY'))

print(response.status_code)
print(response.content) #or print(response.json())
```

I received the HTTP code as 200. But I don't know how to retrieve the data from a possible GET (list of example of possible GETs below).

For example, I tried response=

```
requests.get("https://{appname}.azurewebsites.net/api/country", 
                           auth=('XXXX', 'YYYY'))
```

To retrieve the possible countries and get the error 401.

He sent me a list of possible GETs.

For example:

GET  ​/api​/Country

GET  /api/bike/{id}

...

(the list of possible GETs and POSTs are located in SWAGGER).

I am new with APIs so any tips would help :)

Comment: I tried with Postman but how can I access an Azure API from it ?

Comment: No I do not have any tokens... How can I get one ?

Comment: @RoadRunner I wish but he is very busy and does not help interns ... :(

Comment: No it gives me the error code 400 and 
{'error': 'invalid_request', 'error_description': 'The specified HTTP method is not valid.'}

Comment: it gives me the error code 400 and {'error': 'invalid_request', 'error_description': 'The specified HTTP method is not valid.'}

Comment: Have you tried POST request? You need to play around and see what works. I'm suprised your boss gave you an endpoint but didn't tell you how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the response's body, by the following code instruction

```
import requests

response = requests.get(...)

json_data = response.json()
```

And then process the json data as you want.

Comment: Thank you very much ! But how can I access to the data ?

Comment: No worries. I updated the response to give you directions.

Answer (score 0):

You can decode the [JSON Response Content](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) like so:

```
# If we get 200, Success!
if response.status_code == 200:
    print(response.json())
```

Which will convert your JSON to a Python object, such as a dictionary or list.

The other option is to deserialize the response content with [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads):

```
from json import loads

# If we get 200, Success!
if response.status_code == 200:
    print(loads(response.content))
```

Comment: Yes thank you. But how can I access the different possible APIs from my python script ? for example, I tried requests.get("https://{appname}.azurewebsites.net/api/country,auth=('XXXX', 'YYYY')) but it is not giving me all the data of the countries...

Comment: @colla That depends on how you've implemented your API. Hard for me to say. If you have the API endpoints in Swagger, just use them. It should be the same thing.

Comment: I have acces to the endpoints on Swagger. An example is GET ​/api​/Country but how can I retrieve the data from this endpoint into my python script so that it generates a json ?